# Vlookup to find values related to a referenced cell and sum them up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been playing around with excel for a bit now and I am trying to create a way to look up a text value in another table and add up all the numeric values that are associated with it.

Doing a normal Vlookup off of John will return this.

`=VLOOKUP(H12,H12:I18,2,FALSE)`

[image]

I want it to instead return the sum of all appearances of John which would be 14. I haven't had any luck yet with Vlookup but I not be using the right formula in which case, I have no idea what formula I should be using.

Comment: You will instead want to use the SUMIF function.

Comment: literally just found that... seems to work perfectly... boy is my brain slow today.

Comment: @rwilson, can you have a SUMIF function that has multiple criteria?

Comment: Yes. SUMIFS. :), Unless you mean, using your example, that you want to sum all of Kenny AND John. At that point you could do : SUM(SUMIF(H:H,{"John","Kenny"},I:I))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sumif()](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) or, for multiple "ifs", [sumifs()](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])

SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)

If you need vlookup though, let us know.